# How can I restrict the wix msi conditions to be modified with orca?

Tags: winforms, wix, installation

I developed an installer with wix. With an orca tool I can able to modify the conditions of my installer. I want to restrict the conditions modification in my msi file with any other tool. What I need to change in my wix code ?

Comment: You cannot lock an MSI to not be edited with Orca. As a workaround you could consider to create an EXE bootstrapper over your MSI - [Generating an executable using wix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046320/generating-an-executable-using-wix)

Comment: I created EXE bootstrapper over MSI to avoid making changes with orca. But the problem is I am unable to modify features after installation(if it is exe).I can modify the features after installtion(if it is msi).

Comment: It would be necessary to know what makes this necessary?

Answer (score 3):

You can't stop people looking in your MSI file and modifying it with MSI or WiX features. You'd need to look at these types of things:

1. Signing the MSI so that any modification invalidates it.
2. If it's only install you're worried about then embed the MSI file in an exe (I think Burn can do this) so that running the exe installs it before it can be modified.
3. If you have control over the install environment, put it in a location (such as share) where access can be made very restricted.
4. If there are a few specific conditions you care about, write a custom action to read them from the relevant MSI table to see if they have been changed.

Is there something specific you're worried about?

Comment: I created EXE bootstrapper over MSI to avoid making changes with orca. But the problem is I am unable to modify features after installation(if it is exe).I can modify the features after installtion(if it is msi).

Comment: To modify features after installation the MSI file needs to be present somewhere, yes, to add new files etc, but why does that matter? Adding and removing features uses the cached MSI file in windows\installer and the original MSI to get data, and if you signed that original MSI it can't be changed without it being invalidated. Again, if there is a specific problem you're trying to solve it might be useful to describe it.